# Excel vba can't release winword.exe

Tags: excel, vba

I'm opening multiples Word doc to remove the protection in them.
So basically what my code is doing is that if user choose to enter a password then:
valeur = 6
and pwd is set to a specific value.
My problem is even if I do:  set WdApp = nothing, it still won't release the winword.exe process.

```
Do While Len(F) > 0
    If F = nom_fichier Then                     'file  name 
        nom_original = chemin & "\" & F                     'path
        nom_copie = repertoire_cible & "\" & nom_fichier                'copy of a file
        nom_modifie = repertoire_cible & "\" & nom_en_preparation       'rename of file
        If Dir(nom_original, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then           
            GoTo fichier_non_trouve
        End If
        If Not Dir(nom_modifie, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then                                GoTo fichier_deja_existant:
        End If
        FileCopy nom_original, nom_copie      'file copy
        Name nom_copie As nom_modifie         ' file rename
        If valeur = 6 Then                      'protection removal
           Set WdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
           Set WdApp = Documents.Open(nom_modifie)
           If Not WdApp.ProtectionType = -1 Then                                            WdApp.Unprotect pwd
                WdApp.Close True
           Else
               WdApp.Close True
           End If

           Set WdApp = Nothing
        End If
        GoTo fichier_copier:
    End If                                   'on copie le fichier dans le dossier en préparation
    F = Dir()
Loop
```

So at this point since I called  Set WdApp = nothing  I don't see why it's not releasing the winword.exe.
Any kind help will be really appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a reference to the application and the doc independently and `.Quit` the application:

```
Set WdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set WdDoc = Documents.Open(nom_modifie)

 ... use wdDoc

WdDoc.close True
WdApp.Quit
```

But why not create `WdApp` outside the loop and open docs as needed, quitting the application when your done.